# Is the name change proposal "Second-Language Acquisition" really appropriate?

Tags: discussion

Over on Area 51, one of the proposed names for this site was Second Language Acquisition. While the term does accurately describe the scope of the stack, the part that really bothers me is the "Second Language". Questions on this site are **not** only restricted to a **second** language. It's perfectly fine if you have any questions about learning a third or fourth language. For that reason, I suggest we change this name proposal to **"New Language Acquisition" or something like that**.

Comment: one of the proposed names may of been "Second Language Acquisition" but we are "Language Learning" now which is a concise name and covers all topics about learning language acquisition

Comment: Related: [Final Review: Is the proper title “Second-Language Acquisition”?](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/q/22478/61861) at Area51.SE

Comment: In the research on [**second language acquisition**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-language_acquisition) I have read so far, the distinction between second language and foreign language is often unimportant. So, from a scientific point of view, "Second-Language Acquisition" or "Second Language Learning" would be appropriate. But since the general public appears to make a distinction (well, when they have any opinions on the topic, at least), I would rather stick to "Language Learning". There is no need to add "new" because reacquisition is also relevant here.

Answer (score 5):

Just like "dual citizenship" is usually used to refer to two or more—not "two and only two"—citizenships, I understand "second language" to mean "not the first", rather than "between the first and the third". So I don't think your concern is warranted.

[Wikipedia defines a second language as](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_language)

> a language that is not the native language of the speaker, but that is used in the locale of that person. In contrast, a foreign language is a language that is learned in an area where that language is not generally spoken.

So one could make the argument that it's excluding *foreign language learning*, but not that it's excluding learning a third or fourth language. It's simply not what that term means.

---

That being said, the current title "Language Learning" seems very clear to me, and I don't see why it would need to be changed.

Answer (score 3):

For future readers: questions about [native language acquisition](https://languagelearning.meta.stackexchange.com/q/70/800), including re-acquisition, are also on-topic. So the name "Second Language Acquisition" would be a bad fit for the site.