# Do we need the tag [l2-acquisition]?

Tags: discussion, tags

Isn't [l2-acquisition](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/l2-acquisition) essentially the purpose of this site?

Could it not be applied to every question here?

Answer (score 2):

Not the entire site is about second-language acquisition; [native language acquisition](https://languagelearning.meta.stackexchange.com/q/70/800) is also on topic. If fact, we have more questions tagged [native-language](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/native-language) than questions tagged [l2-acquisition](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/l2-acquisition).

However, [l2-acquisition](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/l2-acquisition) is a very broad tag. Perhaps we should limit its scope to **just the second language**, to distinguish it from **foreign language learning in general** and from **third-language acquisition**, which is a research topic in its own right.